# uploading a pre-made laravel website on cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

i have a pre-made laravel website and all the files in it are shown in this picture below:
[image of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsClF.png)

my question is that how can i install larvel on cpanel and upload all these files?
in which folder should i place these files respectively ?
should i install laravel first and then upload these files on cPanel?
or should i directly upload these files on the server?

should there be any changes in coding after uploading these files?

Comment: use filezilla and upload all laravel files & directories(folder) on cpanel. don't install laravel on cpanel

Comment: cpanel changes: database, base path or config file

Comment: thank you guys . :) i'll do that and if had any problem i'll surely contact you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with these steps.

1 - First make an new **folder** name anything it for **eg:-myapp**.

2 - Now in **myapp** folder paste all the files of **public** folder.

3 - And now in **myapp** folder make an new folder named anything like **eg:-code**.

4 - Now paste all the **files and folder** of remaining content of your laravel app **except public folder content** in **code** folder.

5 - Now the main thing open index.php file which is placed in **myapp** folder root.

6 - Change these two directory path **require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';** and **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';**.

7 - Just change the path these files with your new folder named **code**. like eg:- **require __DIR__.'code/vendor/autoload.php'; and $app = require_once __DIR__.'code/bootstrap/app.php';** and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Copy all files and folders in /public html
2. Copy all content of public folder and paste it in document root (
   i.e. public_html ) Remove the public folder
3. Open your bootstrap/paths.php and then changed 'public' =>
   **DIR**.'/../public', into 'public' => **DIR**.'/..',

and finally in index.php,

Change

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

into

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Then Check you Laravel application